# How to write code to change width/height of video

Tags: html, css

How should I write html/CSS code to change width/height of video(mp4)?
Here are my code.

```
---html---

    <link rel=”stylesheet” href=../../css/videos.css> ←this path is correct        
    
    <table width="550" height="489" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
          <tr>
            <td width="10"><img src="../../images/some/something.gif" width="10" height="489"></td>
            <td>
                <video controls autoplay loop muted class="videos">
                  <source src="something.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                </video>
            </td>
          </tr>


---videos.css---

.videos {
    width: 450px;
    height: 450px;
}
```

In this code, width/height of the video didn't change.
Can anyone help please? Thank you.

Comment: Thank you! I resolved this problem. it was just a mistake using strange charactor for double quotation  → <link rel=”stylesheet” href=../../css/videos.css>

Answer (score 0):

your code seems correct. check this [link](https://jsfiddle.net/Elhambgh/enusz8mr/2/). it is better not to set the height of your video.

```
        .videos {
    width: 450px;
}
table {
  border-spacing: 0;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Code is correct. Check the code if you need to use `height` and `object-fit: cover;` Property.

```css
.videos {
    width: 450px;
    height: 450px;
    object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<table width="550" height="489" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
     <tr>
       <td width="10"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1432958576632-8a39f6b97dc7?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&w=400&fit=max&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjE0NTg5fQ&s=6ecedc1e639d8a4b77aa8e85f4962f03" width="10" height="489"></td>
       <td>

         <video class="videos" controls autoplay loop muted>
           <source src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/video/Crossroad.mp4" type="video/mp4">
         </video>

       </td>
     </tr>
   </table>
```